# Editing to enter a too long tag name and cancelling the edit still causes the "tag name too long" error balloon to display

Tags: bug, tags, edits, cancel

I tried editing a question to add a tag (the question was migrated from another site and came across untagged) and the best I could think of was adding a new one. Unfortunately the name I picked to try for it was too long. In the end, I decided to cancel the edit, but *cancelling* caused the balloon saying "The tag '...' is too long; the maximum length is 25 characters" to be displayed.

**I would expect** a cancelled edit to not trigger any such validation logic, so that if I edit a question to add a tag "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and click "cancel" rather than "save", the error balloon should not be displayed.

Comment: If you want to just cancel your edit anyway, why can't you go navigate back to the question, instead of specifying that you want to cancel it. I usually just close the tab if I want to cancel an edit I was planning to make.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code That's what those of us who work with these things refer to as a "workaround". Sometimes, workarounds are useful or even necessary, particularly for actual problems until a proper fix can be deployed. Other times, like this (when the issue is essentially cosmetic) they detract attention from the fact that an issue exists at all.

Comment: Does this bug still exist today?

Comment: It seems like this bug was fixed as part of the change to make the tag too long prompt show as part of the field rather than as a balloon popup.